# Is this tag a [forgery]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

[forgery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forgery) has no tag wiki, no synonyms, and 9 questions.

It has been used for to denote digital signature forgery, video file forgery, image forgery, cross-site-request forgery, AJAX request forgery (is that even a thing?), file timestamp forgery, a [Ruby library called Forgery](https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery), and some totally unintelligible stuff...

Actually, I don't think I've ever seen so not-quite-related topics stuffed into one tag.

I'd go for disambiguating it, but it seems to much of a bother for just 18 questions, and I'm not really sure which usages of [forgery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forgery) are good enough to keep (I guess the ruby lib is the best candidate since [csrf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csrf) already exists). So burnination seems like a good idea, too.

What should we do with this blatant [forgery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forgery) of a tag?

Comment: I've done a big edit to one question, 17 to go :-)

Comment: Since we have [csrf], I retagged those questions.  I don't really have an opinion on the rest.

Comment: @JasonMArcher: thanks for your contribution! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 years later ...

There were 8 questions left, most of which were related to the ruby library. I created a different tag [ruby-forgery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-forgery) for that. I removed the tag from those which were meant to be for CSRF forgery.

I closed the off-topic posts, and deleted the unsalvagable ones. [forgery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forgery) has been *burninated*.

[image]

There is another [protect-from-forgery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protect-from-forgery), but that's for another day.